# What are the "root", "home" and "swap" block devices and how do I remove them?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, partition, system-installation

[image]

Anyone know how to remove these block devices? I want everything in one partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three block devices are logical volumes in an LVM volume group, `fedora`. `swap` is used for swap (spill-over for RAM), `home` is used to store all your personal data, and `root` is used for everything else (programs, system configuration, system logs...).

There are good reasons for these three devices to be separate:

- swap works better as a separate block device (the alternative is a swap file, but the last time I checked that was slower);
- keeping system and personal files separate means you can re-install a system without wiping all your data.

If you really want to merge everything into a single partition (*which I do not recommend*), here are the steps involved, **assuming all your existing data fits in 54GB**:

1. Log out, and log in as `root`.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Create a new directory for your data:

   `mkdir /home2`
4. Move all your data across:

   `mv -t /home2 /home/*`
5. Unmount home:

   `umount /home`
6. Disable swap:

   `swapoff -a`
7. Create a swap file:

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=8192`
8. Edit `/etc/fstab` to remove the line concerning `home` and replace `/dev/fedora/swap` with `/swap`.
9. Rename your new `/home`:

   `rmdir /home`
   `mv /home2 /home`
10. Enable your swap file:

    `swapon -a`
11. Using a program such as `gparted`, remove the `swap` and `home` volumes and resize `root`.
12. Log out and log back in as yourself, you're done.

Comment: Thanks man, I just going to keep it the way it is. I mainly wanted to get info since I was never used to separate volumes on my previous distro, Debian.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this using a UI that will guide you through the process is GParted, otherwise you could delete/modify partitions with fdisk in the command line.